# How to read only a specific range of lines out of a csv file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How can I only read from line 5000 to 6000 in this csv file for example? At this moment "for row in reader:" loops through all lines of course.

So I have the lines:

```
with open('A.csv', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
     for row in reader:
           response = urllib2.urlopen(row[12])
```

This code is used to open specific url links.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because csv [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object supports iteration, you can simply use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice any specific part that you want.

```
from itertools import islice

with open('A.csv', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
     for row in islice(reader,5000,6000):
           response = urllib2.urlopen(row[12])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator in your `for` loop with `enumerate`:

```
with open('A.csv', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
     for row in (r for i, r in enumerate(reader) if 5000<=i<=6000):
           response = urllib2.urlopen(row[12])
```

Since `csv.reader`, `enumerate` and the generator expression itself are all generators, you will be only dealing with one at a time.